# Facing error when starting prometheus service

Tags: prometheus

I am using the following tutorial [url](https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/setup-prometheus-and-exporters/)
I am new to prometheus.

error as follows:
**Failed to start prometheus.service: Unit prometheus.service has a bad unit file setting.**

Trace as follows:

```
systemctl status prometheus.service 
○ prometheus.service - Prometheus Server
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit prometheus.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/

Sep 26 02:17:00 fedora systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service:13: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ~/prometheus/prometheus
Sep 26 02:17:00 fedora systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
Sep 26 02:19:00 fedora systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service:13: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ~/prometheus/prometheus
Sep 26 02:19:00 fedora systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
Sep 26 02:20:34 fedora systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service:13: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ~/prometheus/prometheus
Sep 26 02:20:34 fedora systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
Sep 26 02:23:48 fedora systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service:13: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ~/prometheus/prometheus
Sep 26 02:23:48 fedora systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
```

prometheus.service file as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Restart=on-failure

#Change this line if you download the 
#Prometheus on different path user

ExecStart=~/prometheus/prometheus --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus/data/ --web.external-url=http://myurl.com:9090

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute path in prometheus.service file:

```
ExecStart=/xxx/yyy/zzz/prometheus/prometheus ...
```